# How can I loop these prompts? I need to ask 5 employees their name and then their monthly sales

Tags: javascript, loops, variables

> If I run the program and enter "John" and "15000" into the prompt boxes, the alert box says "John your salary this month is $1,5000undefined". For some reason the program is not factoring in the Bonus. The alert box should read "John your salary this month is $2,500."

```js
<script>
var EmployeeName, EmployeeSales, Bonus, Commission;
/* The employee's bonus depends on the information they enter in the prompt box*/
if(EmployeeSales < 1001) {
Bonus= 0;
}
else if(EmployeeSales > 1000 && EmployeeSales <10001) {
Bonus= 100;
}
else if(EmployeeSales > 10000) {
Bonus= 1000;
}

/*These prompt boxes get information from the user in order to calculate their bonus & commission*/
for(i=0; i <= 5; i++) {
EmployeeName = prompt("Please enter your name.");
EmployeeSales = prompt("Please enter your monthly sales");
alert(EmployeeName + " your salary this month is" + " $" + 
(EmployeeSales * 0.1) + Bonus);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
var EmployeeName, EmployeeSales, Bonus, Whole, Commission;

for(i=0; i <= 4; i++) {
EmployeeName = prompt("Please enter your name.");
EmployeeSales = prompt("Please enter your monthly sales");

if(EmployeeSales <= 1000) {
Bonus= 0;
}
else if(EmployeeSales > 1000 && EmployeeSales <= 10000) {
Bonus= 100;
}
else if(EmployeeSales > 10000) {
Bonus= 1000;
}

Whole = (EmployeeSales * 0.1) + Bonus;
alert(EmployeeName + " your salary this month is" + " $" + 
Whole);

}
```

Comment: I just tested it, and it's exactly what I needed. Thank you! I'm brand new to JavaScript if you couldn't tell.

Comment: No problem, I just got into JavaScript two weeks ago. Glad I could help you with it!

Comment: Vincent, I am continuing with my code by adding bonuses to an Employee's check if they reach a certain amount of sales. There must be something wrong with my formula or IF statement, because the result is not coming out 100% correct. Can you take a look and see if you can find the error in my code?

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct if it was usefull to you, so everyone can see this question was resolved and you also reward the guy who took his time to write it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, and following the style of the existing code, would be to ask wether the employee wants to calculate his salary or not and make recursive calls:

```
// Wrap it all inside a function
function askEmployee() {
    // Current code
    var EmployeeName, EmployeeSales, Bonus, Commission;
    EmployeeName = prompt("Please enter your name.");
    EmployeeSales = prompt("Please enter your monthly sales");
    alert(EmployeeName + " your salary this month is" + " $" + EmployeeSales);

    // Ask if should calculate new salary or not, and act accordingly
    var askAgain = confirm("Do you want to calculate your salary for this month?")
    if ( askAgain ) {
        askEmployee();
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}

// Then call it for the first time
askEmployee()
```